# REST API with R Plumber - GeoJSON as Input

Tags: r, rest, raster, rgdal, plumber

I am trying to wrap a function into REST API using plumber R Package. As a Input , function takes a shape file and returns **GeoJSON as Output** after the transformation.

```
#* Return Spatial Polygon Object in form of GeoJSON
#* @param dsn:character Path to Shapefile with Name
#* @param design:character one or two
#* @post /sprayermap

sprayer_map <-
  function(dsn,
       design = c("one", "two")) {
# library
require(rgeos)
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
require(raster)
require(cleangeo)

#Import Shapefile
a_shape <- raster::shapefile(dsn)

result <-
  list("success" = F,
       additional_info = NULL ,
       GeoJSON = NULL)

if (class(a_shape) == "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") {
  a_shape <- tryCatch (
    rgeos::gBuffer(a_shape, byid = TRUE, width = 0),
    error = function(err) {
      return(paste("sprayer map : ", err))

    }
  )

  if (design == "one") {
    sprayer_map <- tryCatch (
      aggregate(a_shape, "Rx"),
      error = function(err) {
        return(paste("sprayer map : ", err))

      }
    )

    sprayer_map@data$Rx <- as.integer(sprayer_map@data$Rx)

  } else if (design == "two") {
    return(paste0("Design Two !"))

  }

  temppath <- file.path(tempdir(), "sprayermap.GeoJSON")
  rgdal::writeOGR(
    sprayer_map,
    dsn = temppath,
    layer = "geojson",
    driver = "GeoJSON",
    overwrite_layer = TRUE
  )

  if (file.exists(temppath)) {
    GeoJSON <- readLines(temppath)
    result$success <- T
    result$GeoJSON = GeoJSON
    return(result)
  } else {
    return(paste0("GeoJSON Creation Failed!"))
  }

} else {
  return(paste0("Please provide spatial polygon object !"))

}
  }
```

Now to make REST API more generic in terms of implementation and use , **Input** of the REST API need to change into **GeoJSON** as request body *(req$postBody)* instead  of shape file path import method.
Looking for guidance how to achieve the same in this case. [Test Input Shape file as well as GeoJSON](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dbJks-6H-Yb3r4CNJ7yeSlsX4YmOAkw7?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just to make sure before I answer. You want your API to accept a GEOJSON file, do some stuff and return a GEOJSON file. right?

Comment: yeah True accept GeoJSON file as upload file or as GeoJSON body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plumber 1.0

Just need to load librairies once. Take them out of your endpoint.

First create a parser and a serializer to parse geojson content and return geojson response. This could be done inside your endpoint too. It just makes it more reusable.

Parser are what handles request body content.
Serializer encode the API response.

I repurposed parser_rds, and serializer_rds, just replaced with GeoJSON functions.

Then you do your endpoint using the just created parser and serializer.

Don't hesitate if you have any question.

Edit : Added a zipping folder serializer.

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(cleangeo)
library(plumber)

parser_geojson <- function(...) {
  parser_read_file(function(tmpfile) {
    rgdal::readOGR(tmpfile, ...)
  })
}
register_parser("geojson", parser_geojson, fixed = c("application/geo+json", "application/vnd.geo+json", "application/octet-stream"))

serializer_geojson <- function(type = "application/geo+json") {
  serializer_write_file(
    fileext = ".GeoJSON",
    type = type,
    write_fn = function(val, tmpfile) {
      rgdal::writeOGR(val, dsn = tmpfile, layer = "geojson", driver = "GeoJSON", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
    }
  )
}
register_serializer("geojson", serializer_geojson)

serializer_shapezip <- function(type = "application/zip") {
  serializer_content_type(type, function(val) {
    tmpdir <- file.path(tempdir(), "output")
    dir.create(tmpdir)
    on.exit({
      if (dir.exists(tmpdir)) {
        unlink(tmpdir, recursive = TRUE)
      }
    }, add = TRUE)
    raster::shapefile(val, file.path(tmpdir, "shapefile"))
    tmpfile <- file.path(tmpdir, "shapefile.zip")
    zip(tmpfile, file.path(tmpdir, dir(tmpdir)), extras = "-j")
    readBin(tmpfile, what = "raw", n = file.info(tmpfile)$size)
  })
}
register_serializer("shapezip", serializer_shapezip)

dothething <- function(a_shape, design) {
  if (!class(a_shape) == "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") stop("Please provide spatial polygon object !")
  a_shape <- rgeos::gBuffer(a_shape, byid = TRUE, width = 0)

  if (design == "one") {
    sprayer_map <- aggregate(a_shape, "Rx")
    sprayer_map@data$Rx <- as.integer(sprayer_map@data$Rx)
  } else if (design == "two") {
    # This should return a geojson too since endpoint should have predictable outputs
    stop(paste0("Design Two !"))
  }

  sprayer_map
}

#* Return Spatial Polygon Object in form of GeoJSON
#* @param dsn:file A GeoJSON file
#* @param design:character one or two
#* @parser multi
#* @parser geojson
#* @serializer geojson
#* @post /sprayermap_geojson
function(dsn, design = c("one", "two")) {
  a_shape <- dsn[[1]]
  as_attachment(dothething(a_shape, design), "response.GeoJSON")
}

#* Return Spatial Polygon Object in form of GeoJSON
#* @param dsn:character Path to Shapefile with Name
#* @param design:character one or two
#* @serializer shapezip
#* @post /sprayermap_shapefile
function(dsn, design = c("one", "two")) {
  # Import Shapefile
  a_shape <- raster::shapefile(dsn)
  as_attachment(dothething(a_shape, design), "response.zip")
}
```

Comment: If want it as an attachment instead, replace `return(sprayer_map)` by `as_attachment(sprayer_map)`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to understand most of the part of code  - thanks for such detailing. Could you please explain more on - register_parser("geojson", parser_geojson, fixed = c("application/geo+json", "application/vnd.geo+json", "application/octet-stream"))

Comment: Secondly, If I want to generate output in zip folder as attachment , how I should proceed. For instance in second case where dsn is provided as path to shape file, I would like to generate output as shape file wrapped in zip folder as attachment. Thanks again

Comment: See https://www.rplumber.io/reference/register_parser.html.